# override plugin using add_filter in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

so i found this :

```
$points_to_award = (int) apply_filters( 'gamipress_wc_points_per_purchase_total_points_to_award', $points_to_award, $user_id, $points_type, $order_id, $percent );
```

inside of the plugin code , how can i use this to override $points_to_award value using add_filter in my function.php ?!

i tried :

```
function my_custom_function($points_to_award) {
$points_to_award = ($order->get_total() - $order->get_shipping_total()) * ($ratio/100);
        return $points_to_award; 
}
add_filter( 'gamipress_wc_points_per_purchase_total_points_to_award', 'my_custom_function' );
```

but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the order ID and ratio like this

```
function my_custom_function($points_to_award, $user_id, $points_type, $order_id, $ratio) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $points_to_award = ($order->get_total() - $order->get_shipping_total()) * ($ratio/100);
    return $points_to_award; 
}
add_filter( 'gamipress_wc_points_per_purchase_total_points_to_award', 'my_custom_function', 10, 5 );
```

Comment: thanks, but it's not working, maybe because there is no "$ratio" in apply_filters. any other solution ?!